# pytest_assertrepr_compare only fails

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I'm new at pytest and was taking a look on how to customize assertions. This example from pytest's website just fails, even if I compare Foo(1) == Foo(1). Any idea why?

http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#defining-your-own-assertion-comparison

Configuration:

```
# content of conftest.py
from test_foocompare import Foo
def pytest_assertrepr_compare(op, left, right):
    if isinstance(left, Foo) and isinstance(right, Foo) and op == "==":
        return ['Comparing Foo instances:',
                '   vals: %s != %s' % (left.val, right.val)]
```

Test:

```
# content of test_foocompare.py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val == other.val

def test_compare():
    f1 = Foo(1)
    f2 = Foo(1)
    assert f1 == f2
```

Results:

```
$ pytest -q test_foocompare.py
F
======= FAILURES ========
_______ test_compare ________

    def test_compare():
        f1 = Foo(1)
        f2 = Foo(1)
>       assert f1 == f2
E       assert Comparing Foo instances:
E            vals: 1 != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange, your test passes for me. It failed at first, but I had messed up the indentation of the `__eq__()` method. Check that you haven't mixed up tabs and spaces or something.

Assuming that's not your problem, I suggest you try running it with a debugger if you use Eclipse or PyCharm. See what values the equality statement is comparing. If you're using Emacs, you could try installing my [live-py-mode](http://donkirkby.github.io/live-py-plugin/) to see what's happening.